# How many massless particles are there in closed bosonic string theory?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, group-theory, quantum-gravity

How many massless particles are there for closed strings in bosonic string theory? Page 53 of *String Theory and $M$-Theory* by Becker and Schwarz states that there are 576 massless states for the $N = 1$ level of closed string, but only identifies the graviton, dilaton and antisymmetric part. So are there 3 massless particles for the closed bosonic string, or 576 or some other number?

Answer (score 3):

These $576$ degrees of freedom are distributed among the three fields. As explained on page 53, graviton is the traceless symmetric part of $\Omega^{ij}$. This means
\begin{equation}
d(d+1)/2-1
\end{equation}
degrees of freedom in $d$ dimensions. The trace (dilaton) is one degree of freedom. The antisymmetric part is another
$$
d(d-1)/2
$$
degrees of freedom. Set $d=24$ and you get $576$ total degrees of freedom at $N=1$ level.

To avoid confusion, $d$ here is not spacetime dimension, but spacetime dimension minus two.

Comment: Ah thank you, so there are 3 then. I suspected this was the case but the wording confused me.